# SAM LOCAL - Cognito username in event missing - how to hook this up?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sam-cli

I am using SAM LOCAL and start-api to test my lambda functions using postman. I use Cognito for user authentication and pass the cognito token to the API Gateway. In production, it works fine. I need the username from Cognito (requestContext: authorizer: claims: cognito:username). 
SAM LOCAL start-api does not provide these.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Cognito works for sam local

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAM Local doesn't appear to be running Authorizer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632539/sam-local-doesnt-appear-to-be-running-authorizer-functions)